# Определить самый ценный вариант вложенного списка

Tags: python, рекурсия, список

Есть следующий вложенный список, например:

```
arr=[[2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2], [7,8]]
```

Нужно в нем оставить по уникальному числу таким образом, чтобы остались как можно более длинные вложенные списки. Например, в этом варианте будет два равнозначных варианта, с наибольшим количеством оставшихся символов в наиболее длинных вложенных списках:

```
arr1=[[4, 5, 6], [2, 3], [7, 8], [1]]

arr2=[[2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [1]]
```

Если это упростит задачу, числа во вложенных списках идут подряд. В моем понимании, нужно перебрать все варианты, использовать рекурсию, потом присвоить более длинным вложенным спискам большую ценность и оставить только самый ценный вариант или варианты. Но вот как реализовать это на практике - опыта не хватает.

Comment: Так начинайте этот опыт приобретать, для чего ещё учебные примеры нужны? Пишете код по вашему алгоритму, готовите  тестовый пример, запускаете (в отладчике, например), смотрите, что идёт не так, исправляете. Натыкаетесь на конкретную проблему там и не можете решить - размещаете тут конкретный вопрос. Из правил: "Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. "

Comment: Трудность для меня создаёт рекурсивная функция. Если она здесь применима. Не знаю, как оформить многовариантность при удалении того или иного элемента из того или иного списка.

Comment: Я так понял нам надо максимизировать длину самого длинного подсписка? При это в общем списке не будет повторяющихся чисел.

Comment: Нет, нам не нужно максимизировать длинну самого длинного подсписка. Мы последовательно спускаемся от самого длинного элемента к самому короткому элементу и удаляем те числа, которые уже встречались в более длинных элементах. Когда попадаются элементы с одинаковой длинной у них могут быть пересекающиеся числа, тогда нужно принять решение какое из чисел в каком элементе удалить, чтобы в конечном итоге у нас осталось при последующей чистке более коротких элементов, как можно более длинные элементы. То есть в примере, у нас было 2 подсписка из трёх элементов, но нам один пришлось сократить до двух

Comment: Вот как раз эта вариантность и вызывает затруднение, я отсортировал, сравнил длины, написал if else, но застрял на этапе, когда появляется два и больше вариантов, где есть повторение чисел в одинаковых элементах и теперь надо принять решение откуда число удалить а где надо оставить, чтобы получился самый выгодный вариант сохранить как можно больше длинных элементов вплоть до того, что можно пожертвовать последующими короткими

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм: т.к. мы не можем добавлять и перемещать значения то более длинного подсписка чем есть сейчас мы не получим. Значит осталось сохранить **самый длинный подсписок** неизмененным. Для этого из всех других подсписком мы удалим те элементы которые есть в нашем выбранном самом длинном подсписке. Потом просто удаляем оставшиеся

Реализация(советую самому это реализовать, но все же):

```
def maximize(arr):
    # находим саммый длинный подсписок и запоминаем его индекс
    best_ind = -1
    best_value = 0
    for ind in range(len(arr)):
        if len(arr[ind]) > best_value:
            best_value = len(arr[ind])
            best_ind = ind

    # преобразуем его в множество для большей скорости при проверках содержимого
    best_subarray_numbers = set(arr[best_ind]) 

    # у каждого подсписка, кроме нашего удаляем повторы
    for ind in range(len(arr)):
        if ind == best_ind:
            continue
        new_subarray = []
        for value in arr[ind]:
            if not value in best_subarray_numbers:
                new_subarray.append(value)
        arr[ind] = new_subarray

def solve(arr):
    maximize(arr)

    for ind in range(1, len(arr)): # просто удаляем оставшиеся повторы
        subarray_numbers = set(arr[ind]) 
        for ind2 in range(ind+1, len(arr)):
            new_subarray = []
            for value in arr[ind2]:
                if not value in subarray_numbers:
                    new_subarray.append(value)
            arr[ind2] = new_subarray
```

Примеры:

```
arr = [[2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2], [7,8]]
solve(arr)
print(arr) # [[2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [1], [7, 8]]
arr = [[10, 11, 12, 13], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [7,8]]
solve(arr)
print(arr) # [[10, 11, 12, 13], [1, 2, 3], [4], [5], [7, 8]]
arr = [[4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9], [3, 4]]
solve(arr)
print(arr) # [[], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [3]]
```

Comment: Руслан, не в этом состоит задача. Посмотрите мой пример. В моем примере. Я специально сразу сделал так, чтобы не было самого длинного подсписка (скажем на 4 элемента). Там сразу идёт два подсписка по три элемента в которых есть общие числа, и нужно решить, какой подсписок оставить, а какой сократить до двух элементов, чтобы в конечном счёте у нас осталось максимум возможных элементов "подлиннее". То есть, в моем понимании надо создать дерево возможных вариантов, а потом посчитать, где будет больше длинных элементов с уникальными числами, этот вариант и будет оптимальный

Comment: Что значит максимум возможных элементов "подлиннее". Можете привести еще примеров.

Comment: arr=[[4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9], [3, 4]]. Вариант 1) arr =[[4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [3]] единственно верный вариант. А вариант 2) [[4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9], [3]] уже будет неверный, хотя сохранилось во втором варианте больше подсписков, 4 против трех, и количество чисел сохранилось то же (что естественно), за счёт того, что в первом варианте есть 4 чисельный подсписок, этот вариант самый оптимальный

Comment: За "ценность" я борюсь тем, что спускаюсь в удалении чисел с более длинного подсписка к более короткому. Но на этапе, когда встречается два и более одинаковых по размеру подсписков, в которых есть общие числа, нужно решить в каком из подсписков выгодней всего удалить числа, чтобы в конечном итоге у нас осталось больше длинных элементов, то есть возникает узел из нескольких вариантов, который не развязать пока не спустишься до самого короткого элемента и не увидишь полный вариант преобразования

Comment: arr=[[10, 11, 12, 13], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [7,8]] вот ещё один пример.

Comment: Вы уверенны что вам не подходит мое решение? Я не максимизирую количество подсписков я максимизирую количество элементов в самом длинном подсписке. Если у нас есть несколько одинаковых по длине подсписков нам не важно какай брать.

Comment: Мне кажется, что такой вариант не совсем корректно работает.  Потому если нас не важно, какой брать, то мы по итогу получаем точно не оптимальное решение. Это не заметно в простеньких массивах, где мало неоднозначности и все сворачивается достаточно просто. Но как только получается более "сложный" список - вылезают неточности "упрощения". Вот где сложный был пример получилось
 [[10, 11, 12, 13], [1, 2, 3], [4], [5], [7, 8]]

Comment: А должны были числа [4, 5] остаться в одном массиве [3, 4, 5], где удалилась бы только тройка. Потому что один подсписок из двух элементов более "ценен" чем два подсписка по одному элементу, как получилось в результате